# iPhone UIScrollView - how to get an image title

Tags: iphone, image, scroll, uiscrollview, photo

I'm ATTEMPTING to learn UIScrollview using Apple's Docs and their sample code http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Scrolling/index.html but something SO simple is escaping me.

How do you tell what image is currently on the screen, so that if I selected one of the images in the horizontal scrolling view, how would I get the filename of the image, or even a pointer in the array, to then do something further with the image?

I thought with Page Control enable I might be able to find a page # and map it to the image. I thought about counting deceleration to count pages, but a flick no full enough will increment it and give a false number.

The last thing I could think of is to get contentOffSet and divide by image size which will give a 1, 2, 3 and I could point to the array (too tired to try tonight... thought I might ask before I waste a lot more time ;-) ).

Any other ideas? I thought there would be a method somewhere that they use in the photo album app.

PS: Here's the code:

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
    UIImageView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

    // reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
    CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
            view.frame = frame;
            
            curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
        }
    }
    
    // set the content size so it can be scrollable
    [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];

    // 1. setup the scrollview for multiple images and add it to the view controller
    //
    // note: the following can be done in Interface Builder, but we show this in code for clarity
    [scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [scrollView1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES;        // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
    scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
    
    // pagingEnabled property default is NO, if set the scroller will stop or snap at each photo
    // if you want free-flowing scroll, don't set this property.
    scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;
    
    // load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
    //NSUInteger i;
    for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Card %d.png", i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        
        // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
        rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
        imageView.frame = rect;
        imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
        [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }
    
    [self layoutScrollImages];  // now place the photos in serial layout within the scrollview
```

Answer (score 2):

This was easy after a good sleep!

```
CGPoint p = scrollView1.contentOffset;
NSLog(@"x = %f, y = %f", p.x, p.y);
```

Now just divide by 320 (if horizontal and full screen image) and add 1 (because it starts at 0).

Hope this helps someone else!

Paul